# Unlimited startup after running the program

Tags: c#, visual-studio

VS2022 starts infinitely after running Winforms

I want to embed a notepad program through winforms, the following is my code:

```
    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 274; private const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 61488;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]

    public static extern int SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process proc;
        proc = Process.Start("notebook.exe");
        proc.WaitForInputIdle();
        SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
        //SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);
    }
```

But after I clicked start, one window after another kept popping up so that I had to restart the computer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRVVJ.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried fiddling/debugging your code? For example, what happens if you get rid of the `SetParent` call?

Comment: Do you really mean that VisualStudio is started again and again? Or is it your program? Or Notepad?

Comment: "one window after another kept popping up" Not able to reproduce with the given code. I do get a different issue though, if I replace notebook.exe with notepad.exe, on Windows 11 it never proceeds past proc.WaitForInputIdle() . It only opens one notepad window though, not sure how you could end up with infinitely opening windows

Comment: I attach pictures about form1 popping up one after another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code in win10. If you wrongly input the notepad as notebook, there will be a continuous startup window. But in win11, I tested your code. Even if you use notebook, visual studio will also Stop running and report an error.

It is recommended that you use the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EmbeddedExeTool exetool = new EmbeddedExeTool();

        exetool.LoadEXE(panel1, "Notepad.exe");  //The specific path to embed the external exe
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Embed external exe
    /// </summary>
    public class EmbeddedExeTool
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetParent")]
        private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "ShowWindow")]
        private static extern int ShowWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int nCmdShow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
        IntPtr WindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        private const int WS_THICKFRAME = 262144;
        private const int WS_BORDER = 8388608;
        private const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
        private const int WS_CAPTION = 0xC00000;
        private Process proApp = null;
        private Control ContainerControl = null;

        private const int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr32(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongPtr", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtr64(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

        private IntPtr SetWindowLong(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong)
        {
            if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
            {
                return SetWindowLongPtr32(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
            }
            return SetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex, dwNewLong);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Load an external exe program into the program container
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="control">To display the container control of the exe</param>
        /// <param name="exepath">The full absolute path of the exe</param>
        public void LoadEXE(Control control, string exepath)
        {
            ContainerControl = control;
            control.SizeChanged += Control_SizeChanged;
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(exepath);
            info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proApp = Process.Start(info);
            Application.Idle += Application_Idle;
            EmbedProcess(proApp, control);

        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Load an external exe program into the program container
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="form">The form to display the exe</param>
        /// <param name="exepath">The full absolute path of the exe</param>
        public void LoadEXE(Form form, string exepath)
        {
            ContainerControl = form;
            form.SizeChanged += Control_SizeChanged;
            proApp = new Process();
            proApp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proApp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            proApp.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
            proApp.StartInfo.FileName = exepath;
            proApp.StartInfo.Arguments = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString();
            proApp.Start();
            Application.Idle += Application_Idle;
            EmbedProcess(proApp, form);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Make sure the application embeds this container
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.proApp == null || this.proApp.HasExited)
            {
               this.proApp = null;
                Application.Idle -= Application_Idle;
                return;
            }
            if (proApp.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) return;
            Application.Idle -= Application_Idle;
            EmbedProcess(proApp, ContainerControl);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Embed the specified program into the specified control
        /// </summary>
        private void EmbedProcess(Process app, Control control)
        {
            // Get the main handle
            if (app == null || app.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero || control == null) return;
            try
            {
                // Put it into this form
                SetParent(app.MainWindowHandle, control.Handle);
                // Remove border and whatnot               
                SetWindowLong(new HandleRef(this, app.MainWindowHandle), GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);
                ShowWindow(app.MainWindowHandle, (int)ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized);
                MoveWindow(app.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, control.Width, control.Height, true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex3.Message);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Embed container resize event
        /// </summary>
        private void Control_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (proApp == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (proApp.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero && ContainerControl != null)
            {
                MoveWindow(proApp.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, ContainerControl.Width, ContainerControl.Height, true);
            }
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The dock of the panel needs to be set to full
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer is amazing and makes me think notepad is my own